# useContext not updating useState variable globally

Tags: reactjs

The user variable in AuthContext is updating locally but when I try to print it outside of the value, it returns with an empty array. Basically im trying to retrieve the user variable from AuthContext in various components, one being login.js, and when I try to use it in that component, its an empty object.

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, createContext } from 'react'
import { auth, onAuthStateChanged} from '../firebase'

export const AuthContext = createContext()

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
          setUser(user);
          console.log(user);
        });
        }
    )
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{setUser, user}}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Login

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faGoogle} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { auth, provider, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider, onAuthStateChanged, signOut, setDoc } from '../firebase'
import { AuthContext } from '../Context/AuthContext'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { collection, doc, addDoc, db } from '../firebase'


const Login = () => {

  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext)
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const googleSignIn = async() =>{
    await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    await addToUsers()
    navigate('/')
  }
    
  const addToUsers = async() =>{
    // const usersRef = await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user?.uid), {
    //   displayName: user?.displayName,
    //   photoURL : user?.photoURL,
    // })
    console.log(user)
  }

  return (
        <div class="loginWrapper">
        <h1 className='title'>Monkey With The <br/> IMS.</h1>
        <button class="loginButton" onClick={()=>googleSignIn()} >Sign in With  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} /> </button>
        <p>Made with <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} style={{color: 'black'}} />, by Het Patel</p>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import { AuthContextProvider } from './Context/AuthContext';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <AuthContextProvider>
        <App />
    </AuthContextProvider>
);
```

Comment: *it returns with an empty array* - why would user be an array?

Comment: Sorry I meant object

Comment: Is the empty `user` value logged by `addToUsers`? Because it seems to be logging outdated `user` when it runs in `googleSignIn`. Perhaps try `const res = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)` and then `console.log(res)`? I think the user credential needed should be in `res.user`.